# Android studio: unknown error

Tags: android, android-studio

I come across a bug of Android studio. When I start my virtual device, it tells me that `Unknown error` and popup a window saying `Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Unknown error.` Then I reinstall `Andorid studio` and `HAXM`, but it cannot work for me. Any one can solve it?

**PS: My machine is: win10 64bit Android Studio2.0**

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/10/20/how-to-ensure-you-are-using-intel-haxm-for-android-emulator

Comment: If you open the SDK manager see if Intel x86 Emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) is checked.

Comment: Try enabling the virtualization i n BIOS. google how to do that

Comment: @Pomagranite haxm is installed in sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your machine does not support Virtualization.
 To fix this, you just have to run the emulator with the system image *armeabi*.
 Go to your Android Virtual Device Manager, and create a new device. Select your hardware, then click next. Here, it is very important to select a system image with the ABI column saying *"armeabi"* or *"armeabi-v7a"*. It should look like this:[image]
Continue with the steps, and your emulator should work and run properly.