# AVD Manager Unknown Error

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

recently I tried to make an AVD in Android Studio. But I came across with "Unknown Error" under "Recommendations" section. I have no idea what's causing this since it doesn't give me any info. Anyone can help me with that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNnol.png)

Edit: I haven't posted the idea.log which it had some things in it that I dont understand after failing to make an AVD:

http://textuploader.com/dk7f2

Comment: If anybody needs, the solution is [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46332056/8644557

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all Intel Image Library and Google API for your desired API. Go to your SDK Manager and check intel system images is installed or not if not then you have to installed it as well install Google API Library.

Comment: I have checked it for the API 26, I have installed everything shown under that section. However I still have the same problem when I try to create the one with API 26. https://i.hizliresim.com/8dYpmW.png

Comment: Did you install `Intel HAXM`?

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/ERPvRA.png There is one thing related that in SDK Tools section and it is installed.

Comment: Please refer to this link for a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226413/android-studio-unknown-error

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work for me. It still shows unknown error + x86 text under it.

Comment: can you run any other System image?

Comment: Sadly no, every choice of System Image has unknown error under it.

Comment: Did you even enable VT-x in BIOS??

Comment: Hmm, It was disabled. However it's still giving me the error after I enabled the Intel Virtualization Technology.